# Download multiple files Java

Tags: java, download

I am using the following code to download a file within the `WEB-INF`

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String b = null;
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) {
         for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
           if (cookie.getName().equals("thecookie")) {
               b = cookie.getValue();
            }
          }
        }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(b+"/logs.txt"));
    String path = br.readLine();
    br.close();

    File file = new File(path+"/Results.xlsx");

    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Result.xlsx");
    response.setContentType(
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

    byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;
    //copy binary contect to output stream
    while((bytesRead = fileIn.read(outputByte)) != -1)
    {
        out.write(outputByte, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    fileIn.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();        
}
```

along with this I want to download another file at the same location `Results.csv` I've tried using the same code above twice but it didn't work.

How to download multiple files without using `zipoutputstream`?

Comment: Don't you use Java 7?

Comment: @fge What difference would that make?

Comment: @EJP easier to write _and_ safer code (`Files.copy(Path, OutputStream)`)-- what's not to like?

Comment: this may help you http://www.coderanch.com/t/365930/Servlets/java/Downloading-Multiple-Files

Comment: @fge So why not say so in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MIME/multipart *responses* are, as far as I know, not part of the HTTP standard. Some browsers seem to support it, but I recommend against using it.

Instead, you could pack those files into a **ZIP file** (using a [ZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html)), and return that as your response. That's also the way DropBox handles the download of multiple files at once.

Comment: I don't want to use zip, is there a way I can download two files one after another??

Comment: @Zedai no there isn't, and the answer explains why (no multipart responses in HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but having them in separate requests if you plan to work within every browser.

Here a sample script for downloading a file via javascript

```
function downloadFile(url, name) {
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      link.download = name;
      link.href = url;
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
      delete link;
}

downloadFile(url1,filenam1);
downloadFile(url2,filenam2);
downloadFile(url3,filenam3);
...
```